# cp: cannot stat 'grandchildren': No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, cp

I am attempting to copy and rename the grandchildren dir to the parents dir and it is giving me this error repeatedly:

```
brad@brad-Inspiron-5558: ~/cli-tmp/parents/children/grandchildren$ cp -r grandchildren ../nephews


cp: cannot stat 'grandchildren': No such file or directory

brad@brad-Inspiron-5558: ~/cli-tmp/parents/children/grandchildren$ cp -r grandchildren ../nephews

cp: cannot stat 'grandchildren': No such file or directory
```

What  I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does this have to do with `r`? Also, you are in `grandchildren`, I'm guessing `grandchildren/grandchildren` doesn't exist. Either go up a directory or copy from `.`.

Comment: the r was a suggested tag i clicked by accident.
 bradmason1990:~/cli-tmp/parents $ cp -r grandchildren ../newphews

cp: cannot stat ‘grandchildren’: No such file or directory

bradmason1990:~/cli-tmp/parents $
is what i get when i try from a higher dir, still unable to perform it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to copy `~/cli-tmp/parents/children/grandchildren` to `~/cli-tmp/parents/children/nephews`, and they both exist, then you can just `cp` using the full path or:

```
cd ~/cli-tmp/parents/children
cp -r grandchildren nephews
```

If you want to copy from within `grandchildren` as in your example, then:

```
cp -r . ../nephews
```

`.` here is current dir and `..` is the parent.

Please note I assumed `grandchildren` exists in `children`. Yours failed because you essentially copied `~/cli-tmp/parents/children/grandchildren/grandchildren`, which does not exist.

Comment: its part of an exercise, and its asking me to copy the grandchildren directory to the parents directory.  i moved up to /children and it let me run the cp but it didnt copy it to the parents directory, instead its now in the children dir

Comment: Then just copy to `..`.

Comment: i believe i did it. i am new to using terminal in this way so i was reading the tree wrong, i just had to move to /children and copy and rename it from there.  thank you